# List of CheckBox in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn [Windows Form]

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I am trying to show a dropdown composed of several CheckBoxes (a list of CheckBox) in a DataGridView. Specifically, the DataGridView provide a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that allows to have a dropdown with several items. However, if you try to add as a datasource of the column a list of checkboxes you will find out that the solution is not working (the checkboxes are not shown).

In the following link there is a solution on "regular" ComboBox: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown

However, I need it for DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. Someone has an idea of what can be done to reach the goal? Thanks for answering (I link an example of the code below)

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Put List of Checkboxes in DataGridViewComboBoxCell for each row of the Grid
    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell) dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1]).DataSource = new List<CheckBox> { new CheckBox(), new CheckBox(), new CheckBox(), new CheckBox() };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified `DataGridViewColumns` in past (OK, not entirely myself, according to some CodeProject cook book too :-) ), so I have some idea.

However this **can't probably work** in this case, there's a problem with this idea. You'd not only need to change how the cell looks, but also think how to store the data. How would you assign a separate datasource to *each single* `DataGridViewComboboxCell`? If possible, that would be probably quite extensive work, probably a class handling the structure and the events.

If I can offer a solution, you can have another object (i.e. another DataGridViw at the side with `CheckBoxColumn` and `TextColumn` which would load on `DataGridView1.SelectionChanged`), or you can populate it in a modal form on `CellClick` of that cell and feed back a list of selected items strings on close, etc. I did that in past many times and I don't think there's an `easy` way around it.

Comment: I haven't looked into nesting a `CheckBox` into a `ComboBoxCell`, so I cannot say what this would involve.  But storing the data doesn't need to be extensive.  If your bound row object already has a nested property (ex. a list of strings), then you could use the `DataBindingComplete` event handler to iterate through your rows and set the source for each `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` (ex. to the nested list on that row object). Few lines of code is all you need.

Comment: @OhBeWise: Nope, the list of string I mentioned is a common way to show selected items, but it's a compiled [single] string fed back to `.Text` property, after you make modifications in the child object. Storing data is handled in the child object. I usually don't use binding, but I get the advantage in this case, if someone can use it.  Creating `CheckBoxCombo` is certainly not just a task of modifying the look of the `ComboBox`, but perhaps it might not be as complicated. I am interested myself, if someone posts a reasonable solution...